# Sum values using dplyr in R for all combinations of variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am relatively new to R programming so I apologize if this question is too basic. I have transactions that show revenue earned from six different types of products. There are three years of transactions. My objective is to find out the sum of products sold for all different combinations of products, which would be `2^6 - 1 = 64 - 1 = 63`, for every year. Meaning, I would have `63*3 = 189` combinations.

For sake of simplicity, I have created test data using only three variables because I wrote a program using `while` loop for one year, which stinks. My objective is to show what I am trying to accomplish. Notwithstanding, I have posted random sample from my original file below.

Here's the test data with only three variables `Car`, `Tire`, and `Services` and `while` loop to show you what I am looking for :

```
    dput(Sample_File)
structure(list(Order.ID = c(171, 173, 132, 174, 132, 174, 132, 
174, 174), Fiscal.Year = c(2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2018), Car = c(2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Tire = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Services = c(3, 1, 4, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 
0)), .Names = c("Order.ID", "Fiscal.Year", "Car", "Tire", "Services"
), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my code:

```
  i<-1
    Csum <- matrix(rep(0,21),nrow = 7,ncol = 3) 
    # Row 1 is used when C is ON; T is ON ; S is ON
    # Row 2 is used when C is ON; T is ON ; S is OFF
    # Row 3 is used when C is ON; T is OFF ; S is ON
    # Row 4 is used when C is OFF; T is ON ; S is ON
    # Row 5 is used when C is ON; T is OFF ; S is OFF
    # Row 6 is used when C is OFF; T is ON ; S is OFF
    # Row 7 is used when C is OFF; T is OFF ; S is ON

    while (i <= length(Sample_File$Order.ID))
    {
      if (Sample_File$Fiscal.Year[i]!=2016)
        {
        i<-i+1
        next
      }
      if (Sample_File$Car[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Tire[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Services[i]!=0)#1 
      {
        Csum[1,1] <- Csum[1,1] + Sample_File$Car[i]
        Csum[1,2] <- Csum[1,2] + Sample_File$Tire[i]
        Csum[1,3] <- Csum[1,3] + Sample_File$Services[i]

      }
      else if (Sample_File$Car[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Tire[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Services[i]==0) #2
      {
        Csum[2,1] <- Csum[2,1] + Sample_File$Car[i]
        Csum[2,2] <- Csum[2,2] + Sample_File$Tire[i]
        Csum[2,3] <- Csum[2,3] + 0
      }
      else if(Sample_File$Car[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Tire[i]==0 & Sample_File$Services[i]!=0) #3
        {

        Csum[3,1] <- Csum[3,1] + Sample_File$Car[i]
        Csum[3,2] <- Csum[3,2] + 0
        Csum[3,3] <- Csum[3,3] + Sample_File$Services[i]
      }
      else if(Sample_File$Car[i]==0 & Sample_File$Tire[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Services[i]!=0) #4
      {
        Csum[4,1] <- Csum[4,1] + 0
        Csum[4,2] <- Csum[4,2] + Sample_File$Tire[i]
        Csum[4,3] <- Csum[4,3] + Sample_File$Services[i]
      }
      else if(Sample_File$Car[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Tire[i]==0 & Sample_File$Services[i]==0) #5
      {
        Csum[5,1] <- Csum[5,1] + Sample_File$Car[i]
        Csum[5,2] <- Csum[5,2] + 0
        Csum[5,3] <- Csum[5,3] + 0
      }
      else if(Sample_File$Car[i]==0 & Sample_File$Tire[i]!=0 & Sample_File$Services[i]==0)#6 
      {
        Csum[6,1] <- Csum[6,1] + 0
        Csum[6,2] <- Csum[6,2] + Sample_File$Tire[i]
        Csum[6,3] <- Csum[6,3] + 0
      }
      else #7
        {
          Csum[7,1] <- Csum[7,1] + 0
          Csum[7,2] <- Csum[7,2] + 0
          Csum[7,3] <- Csum[7,3] + Sample_File$Services[i]
        }
      i<-i+1
    }
```

I have written the code to handle only one year because it was extremely painful to replicate this code for three years. I am looking for a solution that would create a list of 3 data frames, each for three years.

Here's a random sample of size 10 with six variables from original file.

```
dput(Sample_File_Random)
structure(list(Order.ID = c(171, 173, 132, 174, 169, 175, 163, 
186, 178, 121), Fiscal.Year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2015, 
2016, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2017), Car = c(2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5346.25, 
0, 0), Tire = c(0, 0, 0, 8691.55800460666, 3198, 5, 2, 0, 2, 
3282.18), Services = c(3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Insurance = c(4, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0), Accessories = c(94.3, 3749.8, 9308.65, 
0, 2, 0, 1, 633.75, 51.44, 0), Finance = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 14800, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Order.ID", "Fiscal.Year", "Car", "Tire", 
"Services", "Insurance", "Accessories", "Finance"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am really stuck so I would sincerely appreciate any help with vectorizing this..

---

@ Ronak shah's request: Here's the expected output for `Sample_File_Random`

```
Output_File
  Fiscal.Year     Car     Tire Services Insurance Accessories Finance
1        2015    0.00 3202.000        0         0       54.44       0
2        2015 5346.25    0.000        0         0      633.75       0
3        2016    2.00    0.000        3         4       94.30       0
4        2016    0.00    0.000        0         0     3749.80       0
5        2016    0.00 8696.558        0         8        0.00   14804
6        2017    3.00    0.000        4         0     9308.65       0
7        2017    0.00 3282.180        0         0        0.00       0
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah - I have added it. Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: @Ronak Shah - Thanks for your question. You would add those rows because they represent revenue from the same combination of products for a given year. It's written in my question (headline) i.e. to sum them. Also, I have done this in my `while` loop code.

Comment: @Ronak Shah - Yes, you are indeed correct. That's a manual error on my part. I am sorry about this. I have corrected it. Row 178 should be added. Sample output was done manually so errors got in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a compact & expressive `dplyr` solution, which proceeds in three steps:

1. create the indicators for whether each of the services is in the basket or not
2. group by the year, and the combinations of the indicators
3. sum the service values by the grouping variables

Here is the code that does this:

```
df_foo %>% 
  # 1. create the combinations of whether each of the 
  #   products is in the basket or not
  mutate_each(
    funs(In_Basket = . > 0), Car:Services
  ) %>% 
  # 2. group by the year and the basket service indicators
  group_by_(.dots = c("Fiscal.Year", grep("_In_Basket", names(.), value = TRUE))) %>% 
  # 3. sum the service values
  summarise_each(
    funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), Car:Services
  )
```

This gives the output:

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 7]
Groups: Fiscal.Year, Car_In_Basket, Tire_In_Basket [?]

  Fiscal.Year Car_In_Basket Tire_In_Basket Services_In_Basket   Car  Tire Services
        <dbl>         <lgl>          <lgl>              <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1        2016         FALSE          FALSE               TRUE     0     0        8
2        2016         FALSE           TRUE              FALSE     0     1        0
3        2016         FALSE           TRUE               TRUE     0     1        1
4        2016          TRUE          FALSE               TRUE     5     0        5
5        2016          TRUE           TRUE              FALSE     1     1        0
6        2017          TRUE          FALSE               TRUE     2     0        3
7        2018          TRUE           TRUE              FALSE     1     1        0
```

Comment: Your response is fantastic. I am curious - why did you do `group_by_` using `In_Basket`? I thought that `group_by` could only be used for grouping rows and not columns. Isn't it? I am a beginner so I'd appreciate your explaining this concept. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @watchtower the `In_Basket` variables are not rows, they are columns. You can look at what the data looks like after the `mutate_each` to see what the columns look like.

Answer (score 1):

What a nice challenge here....

```
Using your dataset that I called test.  I chose to approach this with matrices.
names<-colnames(test[3:8])
library(combinat)
one<-t(combn(names,1))
two<-t(combn(names,2))
three<-t(combn(names,3))
four<-t(combn(names,4))
five<-t(combn(names,5))
six<-t(combn(names,6))
library(plyr)
myset<-unname(rbind.fill.matrix(one,two,three,four,five,six))
head(myset,3); tail(myset,3)
```

Gives the following:

```
     [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "Car"      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[2,] "Tire"     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[3,] "Services" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
      [,1]   [,2]       [,3]        [,4]          [,5]          [,6]     
[61,] "Car"  "Services" "Insurance" "Accessories" "Finance"     NA       
[62,] "Tire" "Services" "Insurance" "Accessories" "Finance"     NA       
[63,] "Car"  "Tire"     "Services"  "Insurance"   "Accessories" "Finance"
```

Using dplyr to get your sums by year:

```
library(dplyr)
testsums<- test %>% select(-Order.ID) %>% group_by(Fiscal.Year) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
testsums
A tibble: 3 × 7
  Fiscal.Year      Car    Tire Services Insurance Accessories Finance
        <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1        2015 1336.562  800.50     0.00         0    172.0475       0
2        2016    0.500 2174.14     0.75         3    961.0250    3701
3        2017    1.500 1641.09     2.00         0   4654.3250       0
```

Creating a matix of 1's and 0's to multiply by your vector of yearly sums for the same six variables.

```
mult.matrix<-myset
mult.matrix[!is.na(mult.matrix)]<-1
mult.matrix[is.na(mult.matrix)]<-0
class(mult.matrix) <- "numeric"
head(mult.matrix,3);tail(mult.matrix,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[61,]    1    1    1    1    1    0
[62,]    1    1    1    1    1    0
[63,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Convert yearly sums to matrix notation.  Multiply it times the mult.matrix. Bind the 3 new columns to the original combinatoric dataset.

```
year_sums<-unname(as.matrix(testsums[1:3,2:7]))
all_sums<-mult.matrix %*% t(year_sums)
myset<-unname(rbind.fill.matrix(one,two,three,four,five,six))
myset<-cbind(myset,all_sums)
head(myset,5); tail(myset,5)
     [,1]          [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]        [,8]  [,9] 
[1,] "Car"         NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "1336.5625" "0.5" "1.5"
[2,] "Tire"        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "1336.5625" "0.5" "1.5"
[3,] "Services"    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "1336.5625" "0.5" "1.5"
[4,] "Insurance"   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "1336.5625" "0.5" "1.5"
[5,] "Accessories" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "1336.5625" "0.5" "1.5"
      [,1]   [,2]       [,3]        [,4]          [,5]          [,6]      [,7]      [,8]               [,9]      
[59,] "Car"  "Tire"     "Services"  "Accessories" "Finance"     NA        "2309.11" "3139.41450115167" "6298.915"
[60,] "Car"  "Tire"     "Insurance" "Accessories" "Finance"     NA        "2309.11" "3139.41450115167" "6298.915"
[61,] "Car"  "Services" "Insurance" "Accessories" "Finance"     NA        "2309.11" "3139.41450115167" "6298.915"
[62,] "Tire" "Services" "Insurance" "Accessories" "Finance"     NA        "2309.11" "3139.41450115167" "6298.915"
[63,] "Car"  "Tire"     "Services"  "Insurance"   "Accessories" "Finance" "2309.11" "6840.41450115166" "6298.915"
```

This can be cleaned up a lot. I chose to walk through my thought process. You can now take the final matrix, convert it to dataframe, rename headers etc...